# non-concatenative morphology in written arabic?

Tags: morphology, verbs, arabic, nouns

How could you explain or analyze these written Arabic from the non-concatenative morphology point of view? These verbs are derived from nouns.

bakkala  (to buckle)
bukla    (buckle)
tilifu:n (telephone)
talfana   (to telephone)
tilifiziu:n  (television)
talfaza  (to televise)
zayt  (oil)
zayyata  (to oil)

thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't recognize the last two, but the rest are all English borrowings, in one way or another. Probly many more could be found with the same roots or the same meanings in other dialects of Arabic; there are a lot of strategies for what happens to borrowed words in Semitic languages, as the case of Modern Hebrew illustrates equally well.

Comment: How do you know that these are derived from nouns? What about veebs derived from nouns.
How could we use prosodic morphology to treat them and what is our motivation for using prosodic mo?

Comment: Actually the 'oil' derivation is incorrect. زَيَّتَ zayyata means (he oiled), to oil is تَزْييتْ (to oil)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Arabic, but what I can extrapolate from Hebrew, which I know a bit, is that you treat the consonants of each expression in the same fashion as you do root consonants. 
Let's take the infinitives first. I use capitals for root sounds. The root of "buckle" is BKL. The infinitive pattern is CaCCaCa, where C stands for "consonant". Now you insert BKL for the Cs in the pattern, and you get BaKKaLa. The same would be true for "oil":

ZYT + CaCCaCa = ZaYYaTa

The interesting point here is the doubling of the middle root consonant, which seems to be required whenever the root is triliteral. 
The infinitive "to telephone" is a quadriliteral root:

TLFN + CaCCaCa = TaLFaNa

The root for "television" has five consonants, and it seems that the final /n/ simply gets dropped:

TLFZ + CaCCaCa = TaLFaZa

Comment: The interesting thing about such nonconcatenative morphology for me concerns how the segmentation of the morphs is construed. One has to assume morphs that consist of non-contiguous parts, right? In other words, a word like "bukkala" consists of two morphs, the one being b_kk_l_ and the other being _a__a_a. The one morph is then superimposed onto the other. Is this correct way to conceive of the morphology of such words?

Comment: @TimOsborne: Except that gemination isn't part of the lexical morpheme but of the template: i.e. you have a root morpheme *bkl* and a template CaCCaCa, plus a rule telling you that the middle consonant of the root should get mapped onto both the middle C-slots of the template. That's one way of looking at it, anyway. But yes, in any case you have to assume non-contiguous morphs; a few analysts have tried to do without this assumption and use stem allomorphy instead (for Hebrew; don't know about Arabic), but this isn't very convincing (to me at least).

Comment: Autosegmental Phonology (Goldsmith 1976/1990, McCarthy
1981, Lieber 1987) have a tier system that handles the consonant/vowel interaction in Semitic languages.  The fundamental problem is that in order to distinguish radices (roots) and patterns in the way Tim indicates, one's approach must be unit-based. Of the most influential morphological theories, only Distributed Morphology is unit-based. The difficulties with establishing morphological units of form seems to have frustrated many a linguist. But see my angle this [link](http://depling.org/proceedingsDepling2011/papers/gross2.pdf)

Comment: @ThomasGross: What do you mean by "unit-based"?

Comment: @TKR Morphological theories are - among other criteria - classified according to whether they are process-based, or unit-based. The classical distinction would be I(tem &)A(rrangement)-model vs. IP(process)-model. Unit-based morphologies must see non-lexical material, i.e. affixes of all sorts, as distinct units, while process-based theories don't acknowledge - at least - inflectional affixes as units. Process-based theories are thought to deal better with non-concatenative phenomena, such as the topic here, reduplication, etc. I believe there is a way to do all that with a unit-based system.

Answer (score 0):

bakkala (to buckle)
bukla (buckle)
a three consonontal root (b,k,l)

tilifu:n (telephone)
talfana (to telephone)
four consonantal root (t,l,f,n)

tilifiziu:n (television)
talfaza (to televise)

four consonantal root (tlfz)
zayt (oil)
zayyata (to oil)

four consononta root
z,y,y,t
i wish this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much guys!
Are there other languages that apply the same rule as this written Arabic?
Like whenever the root is triliteral the middle root consonant is doubling?
I also want to research other words in wrtten arabic, if this "doubling rule" are applied in other words, but i don't know anything about arabic...

Comment: Could you please post additional questions as a new, separate question? Also, if you are satisfied with one of the answers, please log in to your original account and accept one of them by click the green checkmark next to the answer. :)